# "Upgrading" from OpenIndiana 151a to Solaris 11.1 using IPS

Tags: openindiana, solaris-11

I wonder if it would be possible to "upgrade" from an OpenIndiana install (151a) to the current Solaris release (11.1) using the IPS.

What I have done so far:

- added the "solaris" publisher using `pkg set-publisher -g http://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/release/ solaris`
- removed the "opensolaris.org" and "openindiana.org" publishers (just to make sure)
- tried to start the update process using `pkg update --accept` or explicitly setting the release name `pkg image-update --accept --be-name Solaris_11` - both backed out stating there are *"No updates available for this image"*.